# Pull version label from TFS in TeamCity

Tags: tfs, label, teamcity

I need to pull from a specific label in TFS and then build it in TeamCity.  Is there any way to do this?  I've done it before in SVN with custom steps, I was trying to avoid this. I assume a custom step like the below would work, but wanted to avoid it if possible.

Any ideas?  Maybe a way through the fetch URL or appended to the collection URL that I don't know about.

tf get * /r /version:Lyourlabelname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-7370

> You can run a build on a specified change[set] manually using Run
>   Custom Build dialog.

**Edit**:
Another way is to run tf.exe using the Get command.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx

> Synchronize a workspace to match a labeled version of the team’s codebase
>   c:\code\SiteApp\Main>tf get /v:LLastKnownGood
>   Synchronizes the workspace to match the items in the codebase that are labeled LastKnownGood

**Edit 2**
Also see https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207091635-Checkout-TFS-Label

> TeamCity does not support getting labeled sources at this time. The feature request is addressed by [TW-5061](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-5061), please vote for it.

Comment: Thanks, but we really need it to run from a label and via command line in an automated script.

Comment: I've updated my answer to indicate another way using `tf.exe get`

Comment: Thanks again.  If you look above in the question though, I already suggested that "tf get * /r /version:Lyourlabelname" 

I was looking for another way maybe through the fetch URL, appended to the collection URL or some other method.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reference a post in the TeamCity forums. It contains a link to the feature request as TeamCity doesn't support this feature yet. TFS doesn't support pointing to a label in the URL AFAIK.